# C++ : 2D Array, 10xABC

Tags: c++, arrays

**I need a two dimensional array with these parameters:**

- The first array[0][0] should not be included, this needs to be empty
- The first row should be letters starting from A to J
- The first column should be numbers starting from 1 to 10
- In between it should be filled with dots ('.')

---

My problem is that the first column can't handle the number 10, so it has a ':' character as the number 10.

**So this is what I've been trying to work with but the number 10 shows as a ':' character.**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    char matrix[11][11];
    matrix[0][0] = ' ';
    
    for(int i=1; i<=10; i++) {
        matrix[0][i] = 'A' + i - 1;
    }
    
    for(int i=1; i<=10; i++) {
        matrix[i][0] = '0' + i;
    }
    
    for(int i=1; i<=10; i++) {
        for(int j=1; j<=10; j++) {
            matrix[i][j] = '.';
        }
    }
    
    for(int i=0; i<=10; i++) {
        for(int j=0; j<=10; j++) {
            cout << matrix[i][j] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: ':' is the ASCII character just after the character '9'. For example '0'+10 is the character ':'.

Comment: @zenzty To represent the number 10 as characters you need two characters: '1' and '0'.

Comment: I know why it is not working, I need a solution tho.

Comment: `char` can only hold the info about a single letter. Since the `10` you're trying to print seems more akin to labels corresponding to an actual array of data, you may want to add handle this in the logic printing the actual data rather than making this part of that data. Of course you could create an array of `std::string`, `char const*` or similar, but my recommendation would be to create a print function looking something like this `printColumnHeaders(); for(auto& row : rows) { printRowHeader(); printRowData(row); }`

Answer (score 1):

Instead of trying to hold the labels in the array itself, it's recommended to split them out. Assuming this is a game board or something, it's more typical for it to hold only the data.

You can also use `std::setw` (from `<iomanip>`) to control the amount of padding in your output, which is useful for the row labels and also the spacing between each board position.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    char board[10][10];
    fill(*board, *board + sizeof(board), '.');

    // Column headers
    cout << setw(3) << "";
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        cout << setw(2) << char('A'+i);
    }
    cout << "\n";

    // Rows
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        cout << setw(3) << i+1;
        for(int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
            cout << setw(2) << board[i][j];
        }
        cout << "\n";
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
    A B C D E F G H I J
  1 . . . . . . . . . .
  2 . . . . . . . . . .
  3 . . . . . . . . . .
  4 . . . . . . . . . .
  5 . . . . . . . . . .
  6 . . . . . . . . . .
  7 . . . . . . . . . .
  8 . . . . . . . . . .
  9 . . . . . . . . . .
 10 . . . . . . . . . .
```